# Equation with high exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would appreciate any help with this problem:
$ x^8+2x^7+2x^6+5x^5+3x^4+5x^3+2x^2+2x^1+1x^0=0 $

I know that when $x$ isn't zero $x^0=1$ so the equation could be re-written as $ x^8+2x^7+2x^6+5x^5+3x^4+5x^3+2x^2+2x+1=0 $. I am not sure what to do from here. I have tried using wolframalpha to get the solutions so I know real ones exist (2 of them, actually), but I have no idea how to get them.

Answer (score 5):

As the equation is Reciprocal Equation of the First type,

Divide either sides by $x^4,$ to get $$x^4+\frac1{x^4}+2\left(x^3+\frac1{x^3}\right)+2\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2}\right)+5\left(x+\frac1x\right)+3=0$$

Put $x+\frac1x=y$ to reduce the equation the degree $\frac82=4$

Can you take it form here?

Comment: How many types are there, and what are the differences? - Perhaps this should be a separate question.

Comment: @MarkBennet, Please wait. I'm searching for an online link.

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y^4%2B2y^3%2B2y^2%2B5y%2B3%3D0) finds two real roots, one of which will yield two real roots for $x$, but they don't look simple.

Comment: @MarkBennet, Chapter XI of http://archive.org/details/higheralgebra032813mbp and Article $568-570$ http://archive.org/details/higheralgebraseq00hall should explain it

Comment: References like that have gone out of date, but contain fascinating material - thanks!