# Factorize $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I want to factorize $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ in $\Bbb R [x]$ and $\Bbb C [x]$ but I don't know how to do it.

How I can get the complex roots or factorize?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403025/equation-with-high-exponents

Answer (score 5):

Let $w=-x$. Note that $(w-1)(w^4+w^2+\cdots +1)=w^5-1$.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

From  Chapter $XI$ of [this](http://archive.org/details/higheralgebra032813mbp) and Article $568−570$ of [this](http://archive.org/details/higheralgebraseq00hall)

the given equation is Reciprocal one, divide either sides by $x^2$

$$\text{so that, }x^2+\frac1{x^2}-\left(x+\frac1x\right)+1=0$$

$$\text{or, }\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2-2-\left(x+\frac1x\right)+1=0$$

Put $x+\frac1x=y$

Comment: This is a nicer way of looking at things than the roots of unity approach, if we want *algebraic* expressions for the coefficients.

Comment: I don't always understand what you are getting at, but your answers are almost never what I expect, and I am almost always surprised  by them.  Thanks.