# Polynomial Doubt

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, roots, quadratics

Question :

$x^4 + px^3 + qx^2 + px + 1 =0 $ has real roots. Then what is the minimum value of $ p^2 +q^2 $ .

How I started ?

I started by dividing the whole equation by $x^2$ then we get 
$ (x + \frac{1}{x} ) ^2 + p (x + \frac{1}{x} ) + q - 2 = 0 $
Then put  $(x + \frac{1}{x} ) = t$. Then discriminant should be greater than equal to zero. But now the problem arises that $t$ does not belong to $(-2,2)$ , so taking care of that part leads to solving inequality which I am unable to do .

Have I started the right way? 
One more thing to notice is that the sum of roots of the equation is equal to the sum of reciprocal of the roots . 
How to proceed further ?

Comment: Do you mean "all roots are real" or "at least one root is real"?

Comment: If $q=0$ and either $p=1$ or $p=-1$ then $p^2+q^2=1$ and the polynomial has a real root. So the minimum is less than or equal to $1$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374505/existence-of-real-roots-of-a-quartic-polynomial And https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474507/determine-the-minimum-of-a2-b2-if-a-b-in-mathbbr-are-such-that-x4 And https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439501/condition-for-quartic-polynomial-coefficients-given-at-least-one-real-root

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much this is going to help, but if you use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) you can find the roots

\begin{eqnarray}
x_1&=& -\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{p^2-4 q+8}-\frac{1}{2}
   \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{2}-\frac{-p^3+4 p q-8 p}{2 \sqrt{p^2-4
   q+8}}-q-2}-\frac{p}{4},\\
x_2&=& -\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{p^2-4
   q+8}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{2}-\frac{-p^3+4 p q-8 p}{2
   \sqrt{p^2-4 q+8}}-q-2}-\frac{p}{4},\\
x_3&=& \frac{1}{4}
   \sqrt{p^2-4 q+8}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{-p^3+4 p q-8
   p}{2 \sqrt{p^2-4 q+8}}-q-2}-\frac{p}{4}, \\
x_4&=&
   \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{p^2-4 q+8}+\frac{1}{2}
   \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{-p^3+4 p q-8 p}{2 \sqrt{p^2-4
   q+8}}-q-2}-\frac{p}{4}
\end{eqnarray}

And from here the constraint

$$
p^2 - 4q+8 > 0 \tag{1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but could be a direction to go with:
$$t = x + \frac{1}{x} \in (-\infty, -2] \cup [2, +\infty) \text{ for } x \in \mathbb R$$

We want $t^2 + pt + q -2 = 0$ to have solution for $t$ as above：

$$p^2-4(q-2) \ge 0 \text{ and }$$
$$\frac{-p+\sqrt{p^2-4(q-2)}}{2} \ge 2 \text{ or } \frac{-p-\sqrt{p^2-4(q-2)}}{2} \le -2$$

Then we could get relations about $p$ and $q$, and get the min of $p^2 + q^2$.