# Quadratic substitution question: applying substitution $p=x+\frac1x$ to $2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

By using the substitution $p=x+\frac{1}{x}$, show that the equation $$2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2=0$$
reduces to $2p^2+p-10=0$.

I can't think of anything that produces a useful result, I tried writing p as $p=\frac{x^2+1}{x}$ and finding areas to substitute but have come with no progress. Could someone offer a slight hint on how to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403025/equation-with-high-exponents),

as the equation is Reciprocal Equation of the First type with $x\ne0,$

divide either sides by $\displaystyle x^{\frac42}=x^2$ to reduce the degree of the equation by half

$$2x^2+x-6+\frac1x+\frac2{x^2}=0$$

$$\implies 2\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2}\right)+\left(x+\frac1x\right)-6=0$$

$$\implies 2\left\{\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2-2\right\}+\left(x+\frac1x\right)-6=0$$

Reference : Reciprocal Equation is explained here:

Chapter XI of [Higher Algebra,Barnard & Child](http://archive.org/details/higheralgebra032813mbp) and

Article $568−570$ of [Higher algebra, Hall & Knight](http://archive.org/details/higheralgebraseq00hall)

Comment: how do I know how to write $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$ as $(x+\frac{1}{x})^2-2$?

Comment: @user90771, as you have $p=x+\frac1x,$ and we know $(x+\frac1x)^2=x^2+\frac1{x^2}+2$

Comment: also jee, how do I know that I must divide by $x^2$? thanks

Comment: @user90771, please find the edited answer, hope this should explain the idea

Comment: this is an amazing resource thanks bhai

Comment: @user90771, my pleasure

Comment: These are the kind of things that develop with practice.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Try working backwards. Start with:
$$
2\left(x + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2 + \left(x + \dfrac{1}{x}\right) - 10 = 0
$$
then try to obtain the original equation by expanding then clearing the denominators.

Comment: I dont get how you got the values of constants 2,1 -10 in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

$$p=x+x^{-1}$$
$$p^2=x^2+2+x^{-2}$$
$$2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2=0$$
$$2x^2+x-6+x^{-1}+2x^{-2}=0$$
$$2(x^2+2+x^{-2})+(x+x^{-1})-10=0$$
$$2p^2+p-10=0$$

Comment: what indicates that I must divide by $x^2$?

Comment: @user90771 It's the standard usual method which works well.

Comment: @user90771 You divide by x square because it just happens to work. In general quartic equations are not subject to substitutions as easy as this one.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2 & = x^2\Big(2x^2 + x - 6 + \frac1x + \frac{2}{x^2}\Big) \\[12pt]
& = x^2 \Big(2\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2 + \left(x+\frac1x\right) - 10 \Big) \\[12pt]
& = x^2(2p^2 +p-10).
\end{align}
$$
This equals $0$ only if $x=0$ or the second factor equals $0$.  But clearly $x=0$ is **not** one of the solutions.