# All the roots of $(x^2+1)^2 = x(3x^2+4x+3)$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Find all the roots of the equation :
$$(x^2+1)^2 = x(3x^2+4x+3)$$How do we find the roots in polynomials of degree > 2 ??

Also,
In odd degree polynomials I use Descartes rule of signs to predict the number of real roots. Here, however, it does not give me any clue about the number of real/imaginary roots. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On rearrangement we have $x^4-3x^3-2x^2-3x+1=0$

Like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question/480106#480106), divide either sides by $x^2$ as $x\ne0$ to get $$x^2+\frac1{x^2}-3\left(x+\frac1x\right)-2=0$$

Or, $$\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2-2-3\left(x+\frac1x\right)-2=0$$

Put $x+\frac1x=u$

Comment: How can we assume $x\ne0$

Comment: @Simar, put $x=0$ in the given eqaution

Comment: k. This gives me $x^2 - 3x - 2- 3/x + 1/x^2$ . Further?

Comment: @Simar, please find the edited answer

Comment: Ah! Got that. What about the number of real roots part ?(In general for higher degree polynomials?)

Comment: @Simar, observe that for real $x,$ if $u=x+\frac1x\iff x^2-xu+1=0\implies u^2\ge4\cdot1\cdot1=4\implies u\le-2$  or $u\ge2$ .Here observe that $u=4,-1$

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $$(x^2+1)^2-3x(x^2+1)-4x^2=0$$
$$(x^2+1-4x)(x^2+1+x)=0$$

Comment: Great. Please help me on the second part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

Solve the equation $(x^2+1)^2 = 3x(x^2+1)+4x^2$ with $x^2+1$ as an unknown:
$$
x^2+1=\frac{3x\pm \sqrt{9x^2+16x^2}}{2}=\frac{3x\pm 5x}{2}
$$
etc.