# Solving an interesting polynomial with degree 4?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

So the equation is as follows:

$$ 6x^2  -\ 25x \ + 12 \ +\ \frac6{x^2}\ + \frac{25}{x} = 0$$

So one thing that is immediately observable is that pairs of roots will be of the from $$x_1=-\frac{1}{x_2}$$

How do I go about solving this equation systematically ? I have already solved it based on trial error to get roots as 2,3,-1/2,-1/3. But I need to show systematic manipulations to get there.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Isn't this a polynomial of degree 5?

Comment: Could you please double-check that the equation you typed here matches the equation you're working with? Did you mean $25x$ instead of $25x^3$? And is there the right number of minus signs?

Comment: @ChrisCulter - Yeah edited it. The number of minus signs is correct.

Comment: You could set $y=x-1/x$,

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown - As in ? Substitute y instead of x in the above equation ? wouldn't that unnecessarily complicate things ?

Comment: @DS112: No, use the fact that $y^2=x^2+1/x^2-2$ to express your original polynomial as a combination of $y^2$, $y$, and $1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve for $x$ in $6x^2-25x+12+\frac{25}{x}+\frac{6}{x^2}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787754/solve-for-x-in-6x2-25x12-frac25x-frac6x2-0)

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Got ya. Solved and got the right answers. But how did you reach the epiphany that this is the right substitution to make ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $$6\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-25\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)+12=0$$ and substitute $$t=x-\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: I think $$6\left(x^2-2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-25\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)+14=0$$ is better.

Comment: @Arthur: And $+24$ would be better yet (notice the factor of $6$ in front!)