# Ladder against a wall.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Having a bit of a problem with a question. There is a 4m ladder leaving against a wall. There is a box in between The ladder and wall. The box is a cubic metre.

I have found a quartic to find the length up the wall the ladder will reach. But its proving difficult for me to solve.

$$x^4 +2x^3 -14x^2 +2x +1=0$$

Comment: The downvotes are piling up. And they're right: You haven't even asked a question, just stated that you find some equation difficult to solve. Is it the equation you want help with, or do you wonder if you have the right equation? I suppose you are aware that there is a formula for solving the general quartic, though it rather big and complicated. (And this one clearly has no rational roots.)

Comment: The standard method for a quartic in this form is to divide through by $x^2$ and use $y=x+\frac 1x$ to reduce to solving a quadratic for $y$ and then a second quadratic for $x$.

Comment: "In this form" refers to the fact that the sequence of coefficients of the polynomial is symmetric with respect to its midpoint, here (a,b,c,b,a).

Comment: @MarkBennet I had forgotten that one. I guess it's been a few decades since I had to solve a quartic.

Comment: Another feature of the equation is that $\frac 1y$ is a solution whenever $y$ is a solution. I haven't checked, but it looks as though $x$ is the height up the wall excluding the height of the box. Then you expect a reciprocal equation, because the distance along the ground is also a solution, and the reciprocal property is given by similar triangles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find more about this type of equations under the name [reciprocal equation](https://www.google.com/search?q=reciprocal+equation) or [reciprocal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial).

See, for example, also this post [Quadratic substitution question: applying substitution $p=x+\frac1x$ to $2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question) (And several of the posts shown there among linked questions.)

---

In this particular case, you have:
$$
\begin{align}
x^4+2x^3-14x^2+2x+1&=0\\
x^2+2x-14+\frac2x+\frac1{x^2}&=0
\end{align}
$$

If we use the substitution $u=x+\frac1x$, we get $u^2=x^2+2+\frac1{x^2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^2+\frac1{x^2}=u^2-2$. So your equation gets to the form
$$
\begin{align}
\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2}\right)+2\left(x+\frac1x\right)-14&=0\\
u^2+2u-16=0\\
(u+1)^2-17=0
\end{align}
$$
which yields
$$u_{1,2}=-1\pm\sqrt{17}.$$

Now we have to solve for each $u$ the equation
$$
\begin{align}
x+\frac1x=u\\
x^2-ux+1=0
\end{align}
$$
which yields
$$x=\frac{u\pm\sqrt{u^2-4}}2.$$
Since we have $u^2=16-2u$, this can be rewritten as
$$x=\frac{u\pm\sqrt{12-2u}}2.$$
So the solutions are
$$
\begin{align}
x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{14\mp2\sqrt{17}}}2
\end{align}
$$

Here is what WolframAlpha returns for your equation: [(Link)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%2B2x%5E3-14x%5E2%2B2x%2B1%3D0)
Note that you can switch there between approximate and exact forms of the result.

Comment: BTW is there in English also a different name for this kind of equations than *reciprocal equations*?

Comment: Commenting on your comment. Polynomials of degree $n$ such that $x^nP(1/x)=P(x)$ are often called *palindromes* or *palindromic*. I don't know how official it is. The term is kinda self-explanatory.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Official enough to be [mentioned on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_polynomial). I did not know this terminology, thanks for letting me know.