# $2x^4+x^3+mx^2+x+2=0$ has only real roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

$2x^4+x^3+mx^2+x+2=0$, $m\in \Bbb R$. For which interval that defines m does the polynomial have ONLY real roots.

Tried some Horner rule, Vieta's formulas and Sturm's theorem(although I'm not familiar with the last one) but I didn't seem to get anywhere with none of these..
Any hints on how I should approach it? Thank you

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Apply the method given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x+\frac{1}{x}=u$.

Hence, $|u|\geq2$ and we have $2u^2+u+m-4=0.$

Let $f(u)=2u^2+u+m-4$.

For existing four real roots of the given equation we need that the equation $f(u)=0$

will be have two real roots $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Let $u_1\leq u_2$.

Since $-2<-\frac{1}{4}<2$ (see on the vertex of the parabola), we need $u_1\leq-2$ and $u_2\geq2$,

which gives  $f(2)\leq0$ and $f(-2)\leq0$, which gives $m\leq-6$.

Done!

Comment: This is indeed the answer, could you please expend on why f(2)≤0 and f(−2)≤0 results from −2<−1/2<2? Thank you

Comment: @user466857 It was typo. I fixed. See now please.

Comment: That clarified everything, thank you.

Comment: @user466857 You are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite the equation as
$$
2x^2+\frac{2}{x^2}+x+\frac{1}{x}+m=0
$$
which becomes
$$
2\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\!2}+\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+m-4=0
$$
This equation in $t=x+\frac{1}{x}$ should have real roots, so
$$
33-8m\ge0
$$
If $d=\sqrt{33-8m}$, then the two equations
$$
x+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{-1+d}{4}
$$
and
$$
x+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{-1-d}{4}
$$
should have real roots too.

Comment: Almost; you haven't considered the fact that for $ x + \frac {1}{x} \in (-2,2) $ there are no real values of $x$ as solutions.

Comment: @Cataline The conclusion is *not* $m\le 33/8$; the two equations *should have real roots too*.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(0)=2\gt 0$ and the degree of $f$ is $4$ with coefficient of $x^4$ positive it is enough to consider $f(x)$ has a double root and this root be positive.

Making $$f(x)=(x-a)^2(2x^2+bx+c)$$ this gives $$f(x)==2x^4+(b-4a)x^3+(c-2ab+2a^2)x^2+(a^2b-2ac)x+a^2c$$ from which the system in integers
$$\begin{cases}b-4a=1\\a^2b-2ac=1\\a^2c=2\end{cases}$$ whose solution is$$(a,b,c)=(1,5,2)$$ Consequently $$m=2-10+2=-6$$ It is easy now to verify that $\color{red} {m\le-6}$ works.

In fact, the double root of $$f(x)=2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2$$ is $1\gt0$ the other two roots being negative.

Answer (score 0):

**necessary condition**

It will have 4 real roots.
By Rolle's Theorem, the derivative will have 3 roots and the second derivative should have two roots.

$$f''(x)=24x^2+6x+2m $$
the discriminant must be positive.
$$\Delta=9-48m>0$$

$$\iff m <\frac {3}{16} $$

Comment: If we have four roots then $m\leq\frac{3}{16}$, but why if $m\leq\frac{3}{16}$ our equation has four real roots? Try $m=0$.