# Expressing $\sin(18^{°})$ in algebraic form from $z^5-1$ as starting point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am trying to express $\sin(18°)$ in algebraic form using only complex numbers. I know that when I factor $z^5-1.$ I get an expansion that looks like: $(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z^1+1)$ The exercise then says substitute for $z+\frac{1}{z}$ in the 'long factor' and then somehow derive $\sin(18°)$. I just have no idea how to I am supposed to do this. But knowing how, could teach me something about complex numbers.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you realize that $18^\circ$ is $1/20$ of a circle, so that $a=\sin 18^\circ+i\cos 18^\circ$ is a $5$ root of unity.  So $a$ must satisfy $z^{5}=1$.

The polynomial $z^{5}-1$ factors and a bit of thought gets you to the point where you are, that $a$ must satisfy $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$.  So if you can find its roots, then one of the real parts will be $\sin 18^\circ.$

Divide the above equation by $z^2.$

$$z^2+z+1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}=0.$$

Let $w=z+\frac{1}{z}$ and note the the 2nd and 4th terms equal $w$.  Also note that $w^2= z^2+2+\frac{1}{z^2}$, so by adding and subtracting $1$ we make the above

$$w^2+w-1 = 0.$$

Solve this to get

$$w=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

For each of these two solutions solve the quadratic equations

$$z+\frac{1}{z} = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

Figure out which one is in the 1st quadrant and take its imaginary part.

Comment: There is no need to go to $z^{20} $. A minor trig identity helps us to deal with $z^5-1=0$ directly. See my answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  It's not about "need", it's about clarity of exposition.  Students don't learn when you try to make them drink out of a fire hydrant.

Comment: Ok, I did have a look at your answer again. As you claim $a=\cos 18^{\circ}+i\sin 18^{\circ}$ satisfies $a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1=0$ and multiplying by $(a-1)$ we see that $a^5=1$, but $a^5=\cos 90^{\circ}+i\sin 90^{\circ} =i$, so your solution is wrong.

Comment: It's also surprising that people just upvote without checking correctness. And it's get accepted too. I doubt if OP really checked the details

Comment: @paramanandSingh Thanks for your contribution. Both of your answers helped me learn something.

Comment: @Cro-Magnon: btw you have accepted the wrong answer. It may give other readers the impression that the answer is correct. You may un accept it till the time it is fixed.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Did. Thanks for the pro-tip.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  I've seen a lot of whiny, passive-aggressive, junior-high sniveling on this exchange, but you've gone far beyond what the new "Be Nice" policy demands.  I think you should grow up and quit being a point-whore.

Comment: Evidence points to contrary. You have written a wrong answer and yet got far more points. And instead of correcting it you are leveling accusations. On the other hand my comments do not use any any sort of name calling and instead focus on mathematical correctness.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  Go away.  Everything you just said was untrue.  And _dude_, it's just stupid points on MathStack.  They mean nothing, but you've been obsessing for days.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the fact that $$\zeta=\cos(2\pi/5)+i\sin(2\pi/5)=\sin 18^{\circ}+i\cos 18^{\circ}$$ is a root of $z^5-1=0$ and obviously $\zeta\neq 1$ so that it is a root of $$z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$$ Dividing this by $z^2$ and setting $y=z+z^{-1}$ we have $$y^2+y-1=0$$ On the other hand note that $$\zeta +\zeta^{-1}=2\sin 18^{\circ}$$ and hence the desired value of $\sin 18^{\circ}$ is $y/2$. From quadratic formula $y=(\sqrt{5}-1)/2 $ (the other root is negative) so that $$\sin 18^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$$