# Bi-quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

Solve for $x$, it has four different solutions:

$$x^4 -2x^3-6x^2-2x+1=0$$

Comment: Please write your problem out, don't use images (nobody wants to chase down your problem statement), and also show what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: The question says "solve for x"     x^4 - 2x^3 + 6x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x

Comment: Okay, I transcribed it for you. You should read the MathJax quick help (the math formatting language you use here).

Comment: This is  a `quartic` equation. A `biquadratic` equation has the form $ax^4+bx^2+c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Grouping $-2x^3=2x^2(-x),-2x=2(-x)1$

$$(x^2-x+1)^2=(3x)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the *rational roots theorem*, you find that $-1$ is a root. Furthermore, you obtain  by long division that
$\;x^4 -2x^3-6x^2-2x+1=(x+1)(x^3-3x2-3x+1)$ and can check that $-1$ is actually a double root:
$$x^4 -2x^3-6x^2-2x+1=(x+1)^2(x^2-4x+1).$$

Answer (score 0):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZg0c.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZg0c.jpg)just ssolve the last part, hope this helps

Comment: Please don't post an answer like this. It's much better to write it using MathJax.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I am learning mathjax ,till then please cooperate