# Equation : $3x^4+x^3-10x^2-x+3=0$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, cubics

Solve in $R$ the following equation :

$3x^4+x^3-10x^2-x+3=0$

Im try use sub

$y=x+\frac{1}{x}$

But I don't understand whene and where I use this sub

Please give me ideas or hint to approach it

Comment: Hint:  the polynomial factors as a product of two quadratics.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x

Comment: How about $y=x-\frac1x$

Comment: Hint: First divide by $x^2$, then use $y=x-\frac1x$, as the coefficients on $x$ and $x^{-1}$  (formerly $x^3$ and $x$) have opposite sign.