# What is the difference between a real vs. a linear factor within the realm of complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

When you factorise something like 243z^5 + 32 = 0, how would you determine the real factors after finding the roots of the equation? What makes it a real factor?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Real factor of a function of order $n$ means $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_rx^r$ where $a_i$s  are real and $1\le r<n$

We have
$(3z)^5-(-2)^5=0$

Now $x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$

What if $x-1=0$

Else use [Quadratic substitution question: applying substitution $p=x+\frac1x$ to $2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x)