# What's a good method to solve $x^n+1/x^n$ equation?

Tags: polynomials

Basically I had a problem where I needed to find the sum of the squares of solutions of this $A = \{|z^n+1/z^n|:  n\in \Bbb N ,\: z \in \Bbb C\,\text{ and }\, z^4+z^3+z^2+z^1+1 = 0 \} $.

How I understand these equations are done is amplifying with $(z-1)$ so you get  $z^5-1=0$ but then it gets confusing for me
We know $z=1$ can't be a solution but somehow the problem is divide in 5 cases, focusing on $z^{5k} = 1 $.

So for example $n=5k$, we have $|z^{5k+1}/z^{5k}|$ that will be $|1+1| = 2$  which is apparently  a solution.
And it keeps going for $n=5k+1$ until $n=5k+4$... 
I want to understand why we do this and how you solve for the other cases,from  $n=5k+1$ to $n=5k+4$
I have a photo of the solution this way but I don't know how to post it here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $z^5-1 = (z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)$ and so the solutions of $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$ are the primitive 5th roots of unity.