# Let $A=\left \{ \left | z^{n}+\frac{1}{z^{n}} \right | |n \epsilon \mathbb {N} ,z\epsilon \mathbb{C},z^{4}+z^{3}+z^{2}+z^{1}+1=0\right \}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $A=\left \{ \left | z^{n}+\frac{1}{z^{n}} \right| \mid  n \in \mathbb {N} ,z\in \mathbb{C},z^{4}+z^{3}+z^{2}+z^{1}+1=0\right \}$
Calculate the sum of the squares of the elements of A.

- I know that you start from $z^{5}-1=0$, but I can't understand what $A$ means or which are the elements, can someone please explain the exercise

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: With $z=e^{ix}$ you get $z^n+z^{-n}=2\cos x$. There are only three elements in $A$.

Comment: So i have to find every root with euler and then do the sum? sorry, I don't know that much

Comment: I don't know how you got 2cosx

Comment: It's more that I can't figure out what the questions means

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an $n$. It should be $2\cos nx$.

Comment: Oh it's ok, but how do I apply the formula here, sorry, I don't know how to do by this method, can you please show me a little more detailed?

Comment: Oh ok , i got it , but what do I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $z^5=1,z\ne1, $

so, the unique members of $A$ are $f(n)=z^n+\dfrac1{z^n}; n=1,2$  as $f(1)=f(5-1), f(2)=f(5-2)$

Like [Quadratic substitution question: applying substitution $p=x+\frac1x$ to $2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x)  divide both sides by $z^2$

$$z^2+\dfrac1{z^2}+z+\dfrac1z+1=0$$

$$\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)^2+z+\dfrac1z-1=0$$

We need to find $$f^2(1)+f^2(2)$$
$$=z^2+\dfrac1{z^2}+2+z^4+\dfrac1{z^4}+2$$
$$=z^2+\dfrac1{z^2}+z+\dfrac1{z}+4=?$$  as $z^4=\dfrac1z$

Comment: So I don't understand why you took only n=1,2, since there are 4 solutions. Is it because polynomials have symetrical complex roots?

Comment: And I can't figure out what do you mean by f(1)=f(5-1), and f(2), why is it like that?

Comment: @Notimportant, As $z^4=\dfrac{z^5}z=\dfrac1z\implies f(4)=f(1)$  right?

Comment: Why isn't it f(2)=f(5-2)?

Comment: Yeah, i got the first part why f(1)

Comment: @Notimportant, Typo rectifed

Comment: Oh ok sorry, thanks for clearing that out, one more thing is why don't we take f(3) squared and f(4) also?

Comment: @Notimportant, I said "unique members". If you allow repetition, then we need to include them and consequently the  resultant sum will be doubled, right?

Comment: So after that we use the equation above like t^2  + t- 1=0 and put it in t^2 +t +2 and we get 3?

Comment: @Notimportant, Yes, if you need the sum of unique elements

Comment: So if we get for all the elements, do we get 2*3+1? The answer is 7 so I suppose it is the 4 solutions and 1?

Comment: Oh the thing is it is modulus, like the sum of the modulus

Comment: Basically for the answer they took f(0) aswell

Comment: @Notimportant, But $$z=1$$ is not a root of the given equation, right?

Comment: Well yes, that is true, but i don't know why in my book they took f(0) as a solution too

Comment: like f(0)^2 +f(1)^2 + f(2)^2

Comment: They also took f(0)^2= (1+1)^2 =4  and added to the rest