Let $a,b,c,d$ be real roots of $x^4-px^3+qx^2-px+1=0$ $(a>b>c>d>0)$. Prove that $ad=bc=1$.

Let $a,b,c,d$ be real roots of $x^4-px^3+qx^2-px+1 = 0\; (a>b>c>d>0).$ Prove that $ad=bc=1$.

My approach: $abcd=1$, and
$$
a+b+c+d = \frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c + \frac1d, 
$$
which can be shown using Vieta's theorem.
Rearranging, we get
$$
(a+d) - \biggl(\frac1a + \frac1d\biggr) 
= (c+b) - \biggl(\frac1c + \frac1b\biggr).
$$
Further we get
$$
(a+d)(1-bc) = (b+c)(1-ad)
$$
using $abcd=1$.
I am stuck here how do I show that $1-bc$ and $1-ad$ must be $0$?

Let $f(x)$ be your polynomial. What is $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, and how are its roots related to those of $f(x)$?

Don't keep switching out of MathJax over and over. You can put = and > inside the $...$ expressions.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x

If $ad>1$ then $bc<1$ and the signs are different,

I just noticed today, roots are $u,\frac1u, v, \frac1v$.

I strongly suspect that there is a more elegant approach than the one that I will use.  To understand my response, first see this answer.
Similar to the linked answer, the polynomial
$$f(x) = x^4 - px^3 + qx^2 - px + 1$$
is a symmetric $~4$-th degree polynomial.  This is because the coefficients of the $~x^4~$ and $~x^0~$ terms are equal, and the coefficients of the $~x^3~$ and $~x^1~$ terms are also equal.
So, I will take the inelegant approach of actually computing the roots, subject to the constraint that the polynomial equation has $~4~$ distinct positive roots.

Using the linked answer as a model, let
$$g(x) = x^2 - px + q - \frac{p}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}. \tag1 $$
Clearly, the roots of $~g(x) = 0~$ are the same as the roots of $~f(x) = 0.$
Let $~w = x + \dfrac{1}{x} \implies $
$$w^2 = x^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{x^2} \implies (w^2 - 2) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}.$$
Therefore, the equation $~g(x) = 0~$ can now be converted into the following quadratic equation in $~w~$:
$$(w^2 - 2) - pw + q = 0 \implies w^2 - pw + (q-2) = 0. \tag2 $$
This has roots

$\displaystyle w_1 = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~p + \sqrt{p^2 + 8 - 4q} ~\right]$

$\displaystyle w_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~p - \sqrt{p^2 + 8 - 4q} ~\right]$


Further, given any root $~w,~$ the two corresponding roots of $~x~$ are generated by:
$$x + \frac{1}{x} = w \implies x^2 - wx + 1 = 0, \tag3 $$
Note that a value for $~x~$ will satisfy (1) above if and only if the constructed value for $~w~$ satisfies (2) above.
Further the only values of $~x~$ that construct a value for $~w~$ that satisfies (2) above are those values of $~x~$ generated by plugging $~w_1~$ and $~w_2~$ into (3) above.
Therefore, the roots generated by plugging (for example) $~w_1~$ into (3) above must represent two of the distinct roots of $~g(x) = 0,~$ which has the same roots as $~f(x) = 0.$
At this point, the expression in (3) above makes it game over, because when you plug in $~w_1~$ into (1) above, the two roots must have product $~= 1.$
Since you know that plugging in $~w_1~$ into (3) above must generate two of the roots to the original equation $~f(x) = 0,~$ you can now deduce that there exists two distinct elements $~x_1, ~x_2~$ from the set $~\{a,b,c,d\}~$ such that $~x_1 \times x_2 = 1.~$
Further, if (for example) $~x_1 = a,~$ then clearly, $~x_2~$ must equal $~d,~$ and vice-versa.  This is because $~a \times b \times c \times d = 1 ~$ and $~a > b > c > d > 0.$
Also, if neither $~x_1~$ nor $~x_2~$ equal either of $~a~$ or $~d,~$ then you have that $~b \times c = 1.$
