# Show the exact value of cosine of 144° using law of cosines.

Tags: trigonometry

Show the exact value of cosine  of $144^\circ$ using the law of cosines. By this law, $\cos144^\circ=1-2\sin^2 72^\circ$. And that is equivalent to $\cos144^\circ=1-2(2\sin36^\circ\cos36^\circ)^2$. What would be the next steps to solve this?

Comment: That is not the Law of Cosines. That is a double-angle formula for cosine. The Law of Cosines says that if you have a triangle with side lengths $a,b,c,$ and if the angle opposite the side of length $a$ has measure $A,$ then $$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A.$$

Comment: No where did you use law of cosines, but this page shows you how to derive exact values for both $\sin(\pi/5)$, and $\cos(\pi/5)$. 

[link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi5.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't see how this can be accomplished using the Law of Cosines, but here's a way that we can go about it.

Note that $$\cos 144^\circ=\cos(2\cdot 72^\circ)=1-2\sin^2(72^\circ).$$ If we can find $\sin^2(72^\circ),$ then, we will be able to find $\cos 144^\circ.$

Now, for any angle $\theta,$ we have by sum and difference formulas, double-angle formulas, and Pythagorean identity that $$\begin{align}\sin(5\theta) &= \sin(\theta+4\theta)\\ &= \sin\theta\cos4\theta+\sin4\theta\cos\theta\\ &= \sin\theta\bigl(1-2\sin^22\theta\bigr)+2\sin2\theta\cos2\theta\cos\theta\\ &= \sin\theta-2\sin^22\theta\sin\theta+2\sin2\theta\bigl(1-2\sin^2\theta\bigr)\cos\theta\\ &= \sin\theta-2(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)^2\sin\theta+2(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\bigl(1-2\sin^2\theta\bigr)\cos\theta\\ &= \sin\theta-8\sin^3\theta\cos^2\theta+4\sin\theta\cos^2\theta-8\sin^3\theta\cos^2\theta\\ &= \sin\theta+(4\sin\theta-16\sin^3\theta)\cos^2\theta\\ &= \sin\theta+(4\sin\theta-16\sin^3\theta)(1-\sin^2\theta)\\ &= \sin\theta+4\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta-16\sin^3\theta+16\sin^5\theta\\ &= 5\sin\theta-20\sin^3\theta+16\sin^5\theta.\end{align}$$

In particular, for $\theta=72^\circ,$ making the substitution $s=\sin 72^\circ,$ we have $$0=\sin 360^\circ=\sin(5\cdot 72^\circ)=5s-20s^3+16s^5.$$ Observing that we can't have $\sin 72^\circ=0,$ we have $$0=5-20s^2+16s^4=16(s^2)^2-20(s^2)+5.$$ By quadratic formula, we find that $$s^2=\frac{5\pm\sqrt5}8.$$ Observing that $s\ge\sin 60^\circ=\frac{\sqrt3}2,$ we have $s^2\ge\frac34,$ so we conclude that $s^2=\frac{5+\sqrt5}8,$ and so $$\cos 144^\circ=1-2\sin^2(72^\circ)=1-2s^2=1-\frac{5+\sqrt5}4=-\frac{1+\sqrt5}4.$$

Comment: Wow this was great! thanks

Comment: @hersch, a similar pattern is used here (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi5.html), to find $\sin36^\circ$

Answer (score 1):

Using  $(1),(2)$ of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499565/calculate-a-trigonometric-expression-related-to-sin-pi-5/499818#499818),  $\cos72^\circ,\cos144^\circ$ are the roots of $$t^2-\left(-\frac12\right)t+\left(-\frac14\right)=0$$

$$\implies t=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt5}4$$

As $90^\circ<144^\circ<180^\circ,\cos144^\circ<0$

Comment: @hersch, how about this?

Answer (score 1):

Let  $x=144^\circ\implies 5x=720^\circ\iff 3x = 720^\circ - 2x$

$\displaystyle\implies\cos3x=\cos(720^\circ - 2x)=\cos2x$

$\displaystyle\implies 4\cos^3x-3\cos x=2\cos^2x-1\implies 4\cos^3x-2\cos^2x-3\cos x+1=0 \ \ \  \  (1)$

Now if $\displaystyle\cos3x=\cos2x, 3x=360^\circ n\pm2x$ where $n$ is any integer

Taking the minus sign, $3x=360^\circ n-2x\iff x=72^\circ n$

So, the one set of roots of $(1)$ are 
$\cos0=1,\cos72^\circ,\cos144^\circ,$
$\cos216^\circ=\cos(360^\circ-216^\circ)=\cos144^\circ, \cos288^\circ=\cos(360^\circ-216^\circ)=\cos72^\circ$

Taking the plus sign, $3x=360^\circ n+2x\iff x=360^\circ n$ which is clearly a subset of the minus case.

So, $\cos0=1,\cos72^\circ,\cos144^\circ$ are the three roots of $(1)$

$\displaystyle\implies\cos72^\circ,\cos144^\circ$ will be roots of $$\frac{4\cos^3x-2\cos^2x-3\cos x+1}{\cos x-1}=0\implies 4\cos^2x+2\cos x-1=0$$ which is the equation we arrived at in the other answer.

Comment: @hersch, how about this?