# If $A = {\sin(2\pi/7)} + \sin(4\pi/7) +\sin(8\pi/7)$ and $B = \cos(2\pi/7) + \cos(4\pi/7) + \cos(8\pi/7)$ ,Then $A^{2}+B^{2}$ is equal to $?$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $$A=\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{8\pi}{7}$$
>   $$B=\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{8\pi}{7}.$$
>   then $A^2+B^2$ is equal to?

I solve got that $A^{2}+B^{2} = 3 +  2(\cos(2\pi/7)+\cos(4\pi/7)+\cos(6\pi/7))$
From here I am not able to solve. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Comment: **Remark(I)**: 
Notice that : 
$$ 
\cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}) + \cos(\dfrac{4\pi}{7}) + \cos(\dfrac{8\pi}{7})
= 
\cos(\dfrac{6\pi}{7}) + \cos(\dfrac{10\pi}{7}) + \cos(\dfrac{12\pi}{7})
;
$$
also notice that:
$$
\Bigg(
\cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}) + \cos(\dfrac{4\pi}{7}) + \cos(\dfrac{8\pi}{7})
\Bigg)
+
\Bigg(
\cos(\dfrac{6\pi}{7}) + \cos(\dfrac{10\pi}{7}) + \cos(\dfrac{12\pi}{7})
\Bigg)
+ \cos(\dfrac{14\pi}{7})=0
\\
\Longrightarrow
2\Bigg(
\cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}) + \cos(\dfrac{4\pi}{7}) + \cos(\dfrac{8\pi}{7})
\Bigg)+1=0
\Longrightarrow
2B+1=0
\Longrightarrow
B=\dfrac{-1}{2}.$$

Comment: You can find on this site several posts calculating $A$ and $B$. Still, it's worth trying whether you can find the value of $A^2+B^2$ without actually computing the two values. Some examples of such questions: [Trigo Problem : Find the value of $\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{8\pi}{7}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/818749) and [Calculation of $ \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1021947).

Comment: I found the two questions linked in the previous comment [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Ccos(2%5Cpi%2F7)%20%2B%20%5Ccos(4%5Cpi%2F7)%20%2B%20%5Ccos(8%5Cpi%2F7)%24&p=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A^2+B^2=3+2\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)=$$
$$=3+\frac{2\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+2\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+2\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}}=$$

$$=3+\frac{\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{5\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{7\pi}{7}-\sin\frac{5\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}}=2.$$
Done!

Answer (score 2):

$$B+Ai=e^{2i\pi/7}+e^{4i\pi/7}+e^{8i\pi/7}$$

$$B-Ai=e^{-2i\pi/7}+e^{-4i\pi/7}+e^{-8i\pi/7}$$

So $$B^2+A^2=(B+Ai)(B-Ai)=3+2\cos 2\pi/7 + 2\cos 4\pi/7+2\cos 6\pi/7$$

But $\cos (2k\pi/7) = \cos(-2k\pi/7)=\cos(2(7-k)\pi/7)$.

So this means that $B^2+A^2=3+\sum_{k=1}^{6}\cos(2k\pi/7)$.

But that sum $\sum_{k=0}^{6}\cos(2k\pi/7) = 0$, so you get that:

$$B^2+A^2=3+(-1)=2$$

---

More generally, for $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ a prime, let:

$$A=\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} \sin\frac{2\pi k^2 i}{p}\\
B=\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} \cos\frac{2\pi k^2 i}{p}$$

Then $A+Bi=\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} e^{2\pi k^2 i/p}$, and:

$$\begin{align}A^2+B^2&=\frac{p-1}{2}+\sum_{1\leq j\neq k\leq \frac{p-1}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(k^2-j^2)}{p}\right)\\
&=\frac{p-1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{1\leq j,k<p;\,j\not\equiv \pm k}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(k^2-j^2)}{p}\right)\end{align}\tag{1}$$

For any factorization $n\equiv ab\pmod{p}$ with $a\not\equiv \pm b$, you have a pair $j,k$ so that $j+k=a,j-k=b$. For every $n$, since either $n$ or $-n$ is a square, there are exactly $2$ factorizations $n=ab$ ith $a\equiv \pm b$. There are $p-1$ total factorizations, there are $p-3$ factorizations with $a\not\equiv \pm b$.

So you get:

$$A^2+B^2=\frac{p-1}{2}+\frac{p-3}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\cos(2\pi ni/p)=\frac{p+1}{4}$$

---

There's also some elementary Galois theory going on here. If $\zeta_p=e^{2\pi i/p}$. then the Galois group of $\mathbb Q[\zeta_p]$ over $p$ is $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z^{\times}\cong\mathbb Z/(p-1)\mathbb Z$.

The subgroup of squares modulo $p$ is of index $2$ in the Galois group. But $B+Ai$ is in the field fixed by this subgroup, so this means that $B+Ai$ be quadratic over $\mathbb Q$, and it is an algebraic integer. This means that $A^2+B^2$ must be an integer when $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

---

If $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then $A=0$ and $B+Ai=B$ is a real algebraic integer of degree $2$ over $\mathbb Q$. You can use (1) to get $B^2$ in terms of $B$.

For $n$ not a square modulo $p$, you get that there are $p-1$ distinct factorizations $n=ab$ with $a\not\equiv -b$. For $n$ a square modulo $p$, you get that there are $p-1$ solutions to $n=ab$, but $4$ of them have $a\equiv \pm b\pmod p$, so there are $p-5$ terms for $n$. This means:

$$B^2=\frac{p-1}{2}+\frac{p-1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\cos\frac{2\pi ni}{p} - \frac{4}{4}B$$

or:

$$B^2=\frac{p-1}{4}-B$$

This gives that $B=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{p}}{2}$.

Not sure which root $B$ is in general, but it is $\frac{-1+\sqrt{p}}{2}$ for small $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: Thomas please explain how you get these results B+Ai=e^{2i\pi/7}+e^{4i\pi/7}+e^{8i\pi/7}
And B-Ai=e^{-2i\pi/7}+e^{-4i\pi/7}+e^{-8i\pi/7}

Comment: $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta + i\sin \theta$. @Jackson

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

If $$z=e^{\frac {2i\pi}{7}} =e^{2ia}$$

then
$A^2+B^2$ is the real part of the sum

$$3+2 (z+z^2+z^3)=3+2z\frac {1-z^3}{1-z} $$

which is

$$3+2\cos (4a)\frac {\sin (3a)}{\sin (a)} $$
$$=3+\frac {1}{\sin (a)}\Bigl(\sin (7a)-\sin (a )\Bigr)$$
$$=3-1=2.$$