# Find the sum $|\cos \frac{2\pi}{7} + \cos \frac{ 4\pi}{7} +\dots+\cos \frac{12\pi}{7}|$

Tags: trigonometry

The expression can be reduced as
$$|\cos \frac{2\pi}{7} -\cos \frac {\pi}{7} +\cos \frac{4\pi}{7} -\cos \frac{3\pi}{7}+\cdots|$$
$$=|2\sin \frac{\pi}{14}|| \sin \frac{3\pi}{14} + \sin \frac{7\pi}{14} +\sin \frac {11\pi}{14}|$$
$$ =2\sin \frac{\pi}{14} | 1 + 2\sin \frac{\pi}{2} \cos \frac{8\pi}{14}|$$
$$=2[\sin \frac {9\pi}{14} + \sin \frac {\pi}{14}]$$

I don’t think it’s reducible any further, but the given answer is 1. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $\cos 2 \pi/7 + \cos 4 \pi/7 + \cos 6 \pi/7 = -\frac{1}{2}$ has been proven many times, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021947/calculation-of-cos-left-frac2-pi7-right-cos-left-frac4-pi7-right). Since $\cos 8 \pi/7 = \cos 6 \pi/7$ and so on, you can just use the link.

Comment: @TobyMak so there is no way to solve other than using complex numbers? I think there should be one using angle formulas

Answer (score 2):

The error is that $\sin \frac{3\pi}{14} + \sin \frac{7\pi}{14} +\sin \frac {11\pi}{14} \ne 1 + 2\sin \frac{\pi}{2} \cos \frac{8\pi}{14}$.

$\frac{3+11}{2} = 7$ instead of $8$, thus $\sin \frac{3 \pi}{14} + \sin \frac{11 \pi}{14} = 2 \sin \frac{7 \pi}{14} \cos \frac{4 \pi}{14}$, so the whole thing should equal $1 + 2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{7}$ instead.

Comment: Ok, so it is $2\sin \frac{\pi}{14} (1+ 2\cos \frac{4\pi}{ 14})$. But I am still not able to reduce it to 1

Comment: If $x = 2 \pi / 14$, then inside the brackets is $1 + 2 \cos 2x = 1 + 2 (2 \cos^2 x - 1)$. If you have $\sin \pi/14$ and $\cos \pi/14$ that will be easier: try that first.

Comment: Of course if you know complex numbers, you have $|(1 + \omega + \cdots + \omega^6) - 1| = |\frac{\omega^7 - 1}{\omega - 1} - 1| = 1$ where $\omega$ is a seventh root of unity, but I assume you're not allowed to use this.

Comment: There must be some way using product-to-sum formulas again.

Comment: I totally expect the answer to be found using product to sum formula. Complex numbers shouldn’t really be involved here, at least for my level.