# What is wrong with my trivial solution to finding a cubic polynomial with roots $\cos{2\pi/7}$, $\cos{4\pi/7}$, $\cos{6\pi/7}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I came across a problem in a book recently that asked to find a cubic polynomial with roots $\cos{2\pi/7}, \cos{4\pi/7}, \cos{6\pi/7}$. There were no extra conditions on the problem. It just asks you to find a cubic polynomial with those roots. It was marked as one of the harder problems, so I was kind of confused because it seems obvious that a polynomial like $$\left(x-\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\left(x-\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)\left(x-\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)$$ 
should work.

But when I looked up the solution in the solutions manual, it turns out that you can use an obscure trig identity for $\cos{7\theta}$ to eventually construct the polynomial $$8x^3+4x^2-4x-1$$

I'm really lost. What's wrong with my trivial example?

Comment: Nothing wrong. You will get the same answer, but you will need to do trigonometric transformations to get numbers.

Comment: The question was assuming, without stating it, that the polynomial will have integer coefficients.  It *will* be the exact 8 times your polynomial but you have to show that the coefficients turn out to be the same.

Comment: But as N8tron's answer says, the text made the mistake of not specifying the cubic need integer (or at least rational) coefficients.  This is entire the texts fault.  Not yours.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638874/factor-z7-1-into-linear-and-quadratic-factors-and-prove-that-cos-pi-7-c/638896

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if they didn't specify anything else your solution is correct. But typically people specify things like find a polynomial with rational (or equivalently integer) coefficients meeting the specific property.

My favorite example of when this happens is when people say $\pi$ is transcendental because it's not solution of a polynomial equation. I usually point out

$$x-\pi$$ is a polynomial and then preach the importance of correctly qualifying expressions.

Answer (score 3):

easiest is to take $\omega$ as a primitive seventh root of unity, any one of $$ e^{2 \pi i / 7} \; , \; \; e^{4 \pi i / 7} \; , \; \;e^{6 \pi i / 7} \; , \; \;  $$
so that $\omega^7 = 1$ but $\omega \neq 1,$ and
$$ \omega^6 + \omega^5 + \omega^4 + \omega^3 + \omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0.  $$
Next, for any of the three, take
$$ x = \omega + \frac{1}{\omega}  $$
First,
$$  x^3 = \omega^3 + 3 \omega + \frac{3}{\omega} + \frac{1}{\omega^3} \; \; , \; \;  $$
$$  x^2 = \omega^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{\omega^2} \;    $$
$$  -2 x = -2 \omega - \frac{2}{\omega}  $$
$$   -1 = -1  \; \; .  $$
So
$$ x^3 +  x^2 - 2 x - 1  = \; \; \frac{\omega^6 + \omega^5 + \omega^4 + \omega^3 + \omega^2 + \omega + 1}{\omega^3}\; \; = \; 0 $$

In each case, we have $x = 2 \cos (2 k \pi i / 7),$ so taking $x = 2c$ we find
$8c^3 + 4 c^2 - 4 c - 1 = 0.$