# Compute $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})\cos(\frac{4\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})\cos(\frac{6\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{4\pi}{7})\cos(\frac{6\pi}{7})$

Tags: trigonometry

> $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})\cos(\frac{4\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})\cos(\frac{6\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{4\pi}{7})\cos(\frac{6\pi}{7}) = -\frac12$

I tried showing the equation, but my attempts did not get the result.
I already showed that

$$\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})\cos(\frac{4\pi}{7})\cos(\frac{6\pi}{7})=\frac18$$ $$\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{4\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{6\pi}{7})=-\frac12$$

Using in particular the trigonometric formulas:

$\sin(2\alpha)=2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$ , $\sin(\pi+\alpha)=-\sin(\alpha)$ , $\sin(\pi-\alpha)=\sin(\alpha)$ , $\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos(\alpha)$ , $\sin(-\alpha)=-\sin(\alpha)$ , and $2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)=\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\sin(\alpha-\beta)$

Any hint would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638874/factor-z7-1-into-linear-and-quadratic-factors-and-prove-that-cos-pi-7-c

Answer (score 3):

$$ 2 \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi}{7} \right) \; , \; \;  2 \cos \left( \frac{4 \pi}{7} \right) \; , \; \; 2 \cos \left( \frac{8 \pi}{7} \right) \; , \; \; $$
are the roots of 
$$ x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1  $$
so
$$  \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi}{7} \right) \; , \; \;   \cos \left( \frac{4 \pi}{7} \right) \; , \; \;  \cos \left( \frac{8 \pi}{7} \right) \; , \; \; $$
are the roots 
$$ 8 x^3 + 4 x^2 - 4x - 1 $$
or
$$ x^3 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{2} x - \frac{1}{8}  $$
The sum of products of two roots ate a time is $-\frac{1}{2}$

The original claim is from a method due to Gauss, this time we take
$$ \omega = e^{2 \pi i / 7} , $$ 
next take
$$  \eta = \omega + \frac{1}{\omega}, $$
then look for a cubic (in $\eta$) that vanishes because of the relation
$$ \omega^6 +  \omega^5 +  \omega^4 +  \omega^3 + \omega^2 +  \omega + 1=0$$
Here we find
$$
 \eta^3 + \eta^2 - 2\eta - 1 =
\frac{ \omega^6 +  \omega^5 +  \omega^4 +  \omega^3 + \omega^2 +  \omega + 1}{\omega^3}
$$

Comment: +1 That's my favorite way of dealing with such trig identities, though it's likely that OP is unfamiliar with this.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$cos\theta_1cos\theta_2=\frac{cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2) + cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity $\cos(a-b)+\cos(a+b) = 2\cos a\cos b$,
$$I=\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}\cos\frac{6\pi}{7} $$
$$=\frac12\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)
+\frac12\left(\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{8\pi}{7}\right)
+\frac12\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{10\pi}{7}\right) $$

Recognize $\cos\frac{8\pi}{7} = \cos\frac{6\pi}{7}$ and $\cos\frac{10\pi}{7} = \cos\frac{4\pi}{7}$ to simplify $I$,
$$I=\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}=-\frac12$$
where the result you already obtained for the sum is used.