# A question of Roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> By considering the ninth roots of unity, show that: $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{9}) +
>  \cos(\frac{4\pi}{9}) + \cos(\frac{6\pi}{9}) + \cos(\frac{8\pi}{9}) = \frac{-1}{2}$.

I know how to find the roots of unity, but I am unsure as to how I can use them in finding the sum of these $4$ roots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that\begin{multline}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}9\right)+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}9\right)+\cos\left(\frac{6\pi}9\right)+\cos\left(\frac{8\pi}9\right)=\\=\frac12\left(e^{2\pi i/9}+e^{-2\pi i/9}+e^{4\pi i/9}+e^{-4\pi i/9}+e^{6\pi i/9}+e^{-6\pi i/9}+e^{8\pi i/9}+e^{-8\pi i/9}\right)\end{multline}But this is half the sum of all ninth roots of unity other than $1$. So, it's half the sum of the roots of$$x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x$$and that sum is $-1$.

Comment: How do you find the sum of the roots of unity?

Comment: Let $\omega$ be a root of unity: i.e $\omega^9 = 1$. Then $1 + \omega + \omega^2 + \cdots + \omega^8 = \frac{1 - \omega^9}{1 - \omega} = 0$ using the sum for a finite geometric series. Subtracting $1$ gives $\omega + \omega^2 + \cdots + \omega^8 = -1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You have a typo: there should not be a $1$ in $x^8 + x^7 + \cdots + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Quadratic substitution question: applying substitution $p=x+\frac1x$ to $2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x),

The roots of $$\dfrac{z^9-1}{z-1}=0$$ are $e^{2\pi ir/9}; r=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$

Dividing both sides $z^4,$

$$z^4+\dfrac1{z^4}+z^3+\dfrac1{z^3}+z^2+\dfrac1{z^2}+z+\dfrac1z+1=0$$

$z+\dfrac1z=2\cos\dfrac{2\pi r}9=2y$(say)

Use
$\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)^2=z^2+\dfrac1{z^2}+2$

$\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)^3=z^3+\dfrac1{z^3}+3\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)$

$z^4+\dfrac1{z^4}=\left(z^2+\dfrac1{z^2}\right)^2-2=\left(\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)^2-2\right)^2-2$

to form a bi-quadratic equation in $y$

Now use Vieta's formula

**See also**: [factor $z^7-1$ into linear and quadratic factors and prove that $ \cos(\pi/7) \cdot\cos(2\pi/7) \cdot\cos(3\pi/7)=1/8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638874/factor-z7-1-into-linear-and-quadratic-factors-and-prove-that-cos-pi-7-c)

Answer (score 1):

The roots of unity for $z^9=1$ are $e^{i \frac{2\pi k}9},\>k=0, \pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4$ and their sum is equal to zero, i.e.
$$0=1+ e^{i\frac{2\pi k}9} + e^{-i\frac{2\pi k}9}
 + e^{i\frac{4\pi k}9} + e^{-i\frac{4\pi k}9}
 + e^{i\frac{6\pi k}9} + e^{-i\frac{6\pi k}9}
 + e^{i\frac{8\pi k}9} + e^{-i\frac{8\pi k}9}
$$
which leads to
$$\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}+
 \cos\frac{4\pi}{9}+ \cos\frac{6\pi}{9} + \cos\frac{8\pi}{9} =- \frac{1}{2}$$