# $z$ is a complex number such that $z^7=1$, where $z\not =1$. Find the value of $z^{100}+z^{-100} + z^{300}+z^{-300} + z^{500}+z^{-500}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $z=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{7}}$

Then the expression, after simplification turns to
$$2[\cos \frac{200\pi}{7} +\cos \frac{600 \pi}{7} +\cos \frac{1000\pi}{7}]$$

How do I solve from here?

Comment: You can't assume $z=e^{2\pi i/7}$ like that...\

Comment: Please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189). It looks bad and confusing, and it rarely appears in professional mathematics typesetting.

Comment: Hint: $z^{100}=z^2$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3937022/a-question-of-roots-of-unity/3937050#3937050

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $z^7=1$ we have that it's equal to

$$z^2+z^5+z^6+z+z^3+z^4$$

$$=z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z$$ because $z^{7k+1}=z, z^{7k+2}=z^2,...$. This is equal to $-1$ since $z^7-1=(z-1)(z^6+..+1)=0$ and thus $z^6+..+1=0$ noting that $z -1\neq 0$.

Also we can solve using sum of geometric progression.

$\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}=\frac{z(z^6-1)}{z-1}=\frac{z^7-z}{z-1}=\frac{1-z}{z-1}=-1$

Comment: I am confused, how exactly is the GP related of the question being asked?

Comment: @Aditya I proved that the sum is equal to $z+z^2+..+z^6$ which is GP.

Comment: I understood it now, but you should elaborate on how you got the first line, ie. $z^{100} =z^2$.

Comment: @Aditya $100$ is in the form of $7k+2$ so $z^{100}=z^2$.

Comment: Yes, as I said I understood, I just suggested that you should put it in your answer because it doesn’t immediately click. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Since $$100\equiv _7 2$$ and $$300\equiv _7 -1$$ and  $$500\equiv _7 3$$ We have \begin{align} &=z^{2}+z^{-2} + z^{-1}+z^{1} + z^{3}+z^{-3} \\
&= {z^5+z+z^2+z^4+z^6+1\over z^3}\\
& ={z^6+z^5+z^4+\color{red}{z^3}+z^2+z+1-\color{red}{z^3}\over z^3}\\ &= {{z^7-1\over z-1} -z^3\over z^3} \\
 &= {0-z^3\over z^3} =-1\end{align}

Comment: It's $-1$ since $1$ is not included.

Comment: I don’t understand your signs. Why is there a 7 after the equivalent sign?

Comment: It is modulo 7. You know conguence relation?

Comment: No, I am not aware

Comment: Then just think of $z^{7k+r} = z^r$.

Comment: Okay, that I know but I have no idea what modulo 7 is

Comment: @Aqua It's $-1$ and not $0$.

Comment: @Aqua What do you mean by wrong answer? It's not clear how you get the last equation..

Comment: How is it wrong?

Comment: @Aqua $z^{-2}=1 * z^{-2}=z^5$

Comment: Also the numerator on the second last line reduces to $-z^3$, it isn’t a geometric progression