# Find a short formula for $\sin x+\sin (x+y)+\sin (x+2y)+. . .+\sin (x+(n-1)y)$

Tags: trigonometry, alternative-proof, trigonometric-series

The answer is :

$$\sin(\frac {x+x+(n-1)y}{2}) \dfrac {\sin \frac{ny}{2}}{\sin \frac {y}{2}}$$

I could've written the question as: Show that..., but then people would try induction.

**What I did:**
$$\sin x+\sin (x+y)+ ... +\sin (x+(n-1)y)$$
$$=2\sin(x+y/2)\cos(y/2)+\sin (x+2y)+...+\sin(x+(n-1)y)$$
$$=\dfrac {sin(x+y/2)sin(y)}{\sin (y/2)}+\sin(x+2y)+...+\sin(x+(n-1)y)$$

.
.
.
I don't think that's taking me anywhere near to a solution.
Any better ideas than this(stupid one) will be appreciated. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: Which,.. sadly, makes my question a $\duplicate$

Comment: Did you get your answer? Why your question has to be unique?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, yes thanks, I got my answer. It's just that I don't like it being marked duplicate, shows that I didn't search well enough.

Comment: Go to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773131/solve_problem_of_trigonometry