# Using complex numbers prove that $\sin(\frac {\pi}{m})\sin(\frac {2\pi}{m})\ldots\sin(\frac {(m-1)\pi}{m})= \frac{m}{2^{m -1}}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Prove that for $m=2,3,\dots$
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\vphantom{1}\pi}m\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}m\right)\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}m\right)\cdots\sin\left(\frac{(m-1)\pi}m\right)=\frac{m}{2^{m-1}}
$$

I have no idea how to begin at all, I'm trying to think of a way using de Moivre's theorem but I can't seem to figure it out.
 I'm sorry for not showing effort but I'm completely stuck.

Comment: must be a mistake in the book then, but are you familiar with anything similar to this?

Comment: oh i figured out the mistake, can i re-ask?
correction is denominator of R.H.S is 2^(m-1)

Comment: yes.. my mistake i'll be cautious next time

Comment: It should be $\frac{m}{2^{m-1}}$. The question looks as if it has a typo; it is missing a pair of braces.

Comment: does it make a difference though?

Comment: This is closely related to [Evaluation of $\sin \frac{\pi}{7}\cdot \sin \frac{2\pi}{7}\cdot \sin \frac{3\pi}{7}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784712/evaluation-of-sin-frac-pi7-cdot-sin-frac2-pi7-cdot-sin-frac3-pi).

Comment: De Moivre's identity follows from Euler's formula, which can be used to get the representation $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$. Using this representation is the easiest way I know to show the (corrected) identity in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More Questions from Mathematical Analysis by Apostol](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649011/more-questions-from-mathematical-analysis-by-apostol)

Comment: @AhmadBazzi: you claim the left-hand side is $0$. However, none of the factors is $0$. I fixed the right-hand side, but the left-hand side is unchanged.

Comment: for $m = 2$, isn't $\sin \frac{2\pi}{m} = 0 $ ? @robjohn

Comment: @AhmadBazzi: yes, but the product is up to $\frac{(m-1)\pi}n$ not $\frac{m\pi}n$.

Comment: @robjohn oh goshh.. i did not see that. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalized from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1784790):
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(\frac{e^{i\pi\frac km}-e^{-i\pi\frac km}}{2i}\right)
&=\frac{e^{i\pi\frac{m(m-1)}{2m}}}{2^{m-1}i^{m-1}}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(1-e^{-i2\pi\frac km}\right)\\
&=\frac{e^{i\pi\frac{m-1}2}}{2^{m-1}i^{m-1}}\lim_{z\to1}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(z-e^{-i2\pi\frac km}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{2^{m-1}}\lim_{z\to1}\frac{z^m-1}{z-1}\\[9pt]
&=\frac{m}{2^{m-1}}
\end{align}
$$
The statement in the question seems to be missing a pair of braces: `\frac{m}{2^m-1}` rather than `\frac{m}{2^{m-1}}`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case left hand side of equation is not equal to right hand sides of equation .You can try it by putting random values of m.

Example ($m=3$): $$\sin \frac{\pi}{3} \sin \frac{2\pi}{3} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac{3}{4} \neq \frac{3}{2^3 - 1}$$

Comment: this ought to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Well the equation is wrong

Comment: Well replace a value for $m$ and show your point. You could edit your answer.

Comment: If m=3 then LHS of equation becomes sin(π/3)×sin(2π/3)=(√3/2)×(√3/2)=3/4 now RHS will be 3/(2^3-1)=3/7 hence LHS is not equal to RHS

Comment: You could edit your answer. I'll do it for you

Answer (score 1):

$|\cos \theta + i\sin \theta - 1|\\
\sqrt {1 - 2\cos \theta} = 2\sin \frac {\theta}{2}\\
2\sin\theta = |e^{2\theta i} - 1|$

$\prod_\limits{n=1}^{m-1} \sin \frac{n\pi}{m} = \frac {1}{2^{m-1}}\prod_\limits{n=1}^{m-1}|e^{\frac{2n\pi}{m} i} - 1|$

The set $\{e^{\frac{2n\pi}{m} i}\}$ make up the roots of $z^m - 1 = 0$ excluding the root at $z= 1$ or the roots of $(z^{m-1} + z^{m-2} + z^{m-3} + \cdots  + 1)$

$(z - e^{\frac{2\pi}{m}i})(z - e^{\frac{4\pi}{m}i})(z - e^{\frac{6\pi}{m}i})\cdots(z - e^{\frac{(m-2)\pi}{m}i})= (z^{m-1} + z^{m-2} + z^{m-3} + \cdots  + 1)\\
|z - e^{\frac{2\pi}{m}i}||z - e^{\frac{4\pi}{m}i}||z - e^{\frac{6\pi}{m}i}|\cdots|z - e^{\frac{(m-2)\pi}{m}i}|= |z^{m-1} + z^{m-2} + z^{m-3} + \cdots  + 1| $

and now set z = 1

$|1 - e^{\frac{2\pi}{m}i}||1 - e^{\frac{4\pi}{m}i}||1 - e^{\frac{6\pi}{m}i}|\cdots|1 - e^{\frac{(m-2)\pi}{m}i}| = |1^{m-1} + 1^{m-2} + 1^{m-3} + \cdots  + 1| = m$

$\prod_\limits{n=1}^{m-1} \sin \frac{n\pi}{m} = \frac {1}{2^{m-1}}\prod_\limits{n=1}^{m-1}|e^{\frac{2n\pi}{m} i} - 1| = \frac {m}{2^{m-1}}$