# Proving $\sin\frac\pi7 \cdot \sin\frac{2 \pi}{7}\cdot\sin\frac{3 \pi}{7} = \frac{\sqrt7}{8}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove 
>   $$\sin\frac\pi7 \cdot \sin\frac{2 \pi}{7}\cdot\sin\frac{3 \pi}{7} = \frac{\sqrt7}{8}$$

I tried using the product to sum identities but those got me nowhere. Any help would be great.

Comment: This seems to be the same question as [Evaluation of $\sin \frac{\pi}{7}\cdot \sin \frac{2\pi}{7}\cdot \sin \frac{3\pi}{7}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1784712).  I found it [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csin%5Cfrac%5Cpi7%20%5Ccdot%20%5Csin%5Cfrac%7B2%20%5Cpi%7D%7B7%7D%5Ccdot%5Csin%5Cfrac%7B3%20%5Cpi%7D%7B7%7D%24&p=1), for general advice on searching see: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)