# Prove that $\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{8}$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that
>   $\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{8}$.

What I've tried doing :
If $\theta=\frac{\pi}{7}:$
$$
3\theta+4\theta=\pi
$$
This allowed me to prove that :
$$
\tan^2\frac{\pi}{7}+\tan^2\frac{2\pi}{7}+\tan^2\frac{3\pi}{7}=21
\\
\cot^2\frac{\pi}{7}+\cot^2\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cot^2\frac{3\pi}{7}=5
$$
Is my reasoning wrong or is this entirely the wrong way to approach this question ?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I believe I put it in the title. The other two formulae, I've already managed to prove. I just mentioned them, thinking they would help.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818749/trigo-problem-find-the-value-of-sin-frac2-pi7-sin-frac4-pi7-sin-fr/937553#937553

Comment: Are you adding the sines or multiplying? And where did you get tan and cot from?

Comment: @browngreen Multiplying. I just... uh... found them along the way. I'll just delete that part of the question so it doesn't cause any more confusion. SOrry.

Comment: Through $\sin\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{i\theta}}{2i}$ that identity follows from a Gauss sum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265229/prove-that-cot2-pi-7-cot22-pi-7-cot23-pi-7-5?noredirect=1&lq=1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175736/evaluate-tan-220-circ-tan-240-circ-tan-280-circ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sin\frac{k\pi}{7}=\sin\frac{(7-k)\pi}{7}$ for k=1,2,3 we get:
$$(\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{3\pi}{7})^2=
\prod_{k=1}^6 {\sin\frac{k\pi}{7}}=\frac{7}{2^6}$$
where the last equality is the case n=7 in this question:
[Prove that $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{k \pi}{n} = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1)
So we get the desired result: $\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{8}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can show that $\sin^2(\pi/7)$, $\sin^2(2\pi/7)$, and $\sin^2(3\pi/7)$ are the three roots of $64x^3-112x^2+56x-7 = 0$, as follows:

Take $\zeta_7$ a $7$'th root of unity (a root of $(x^7-1)/(x-1) = x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = 0$), then $2 \cos(k 2\pi/7) = \zeta_7^k + \zeta_7^{-k}$, and with $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$ you can now express $\sin^2(\pi/7)$, $\sin^2(2\pi/7)$, and $\sin^2(3\pi/7)$ in terms of $\zeta_7$. After that you can verify that they are roots of $64x^3-112x^2+56x-7 = 0$.