# Find the value of $\sin(\frac{\pi}{7})\sin(\frac{2\pi}{7})\sin(\frac{3\pi}{7})$

Tags: trigonometry

The value of $\sin(\frac{\pi}{7})\sin(\frac{2\pi}{7})\sin(\frac{3\pi}{7})=\frac{\sqrt{p}}{q}$ where $p, q$ are co-primes then $p+q=$

Not able to solve this question as it requires value on the form of $\frac{\sqrt{p}}{q}$

I tried to convert it into $\cos(\frac{\pi}{14})\cos(\frac{3\pi}{14})\cos(\frac{5\pi}{14})$ and see whether by dividing and multiplying by $\sin(\frac{\pi}{14})$ we can achieve the result but unfortunately it is not leading to substantial result.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191058/prove-that-sin-frac-pi7-sin-frac2-pi7-sin-frac3-pi7-frac-sqrt7