# How to find the polynomial such that ...

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Let $P(x)$ be the polynomial of degree 4 and $\sin\dfrac{\pi}{24}$, $\sin\dfrac{7\pi}{24}$, $\sin\dfrac{13\pi}{24}$, $\sin\dfrac{19\pi}{24}$ are roots of $P(x)$ .
How to find $P(x)$?
Thank you very much.

---

Thank you every one.
But consider this problem.

Find the polynomial with degree 3 such that $\cos\dfrac{\pi}{12}$, $\cos\dfrac{9\pi}{12}$, $\cos\dfrac{17\pi}{12}$ are roots

Note that $\dfrac{\pi}{12}$, $\dfrac{9\pi}{12}$, $\dfrac{17\pi}{12}$ are solution of equation $\cos3\theta=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and  $\cos\dfrac{\pi}{12}$, $\cos\dfrac{9\pi}{12}$, $\cos\dfrac{17\pi}{12}$ are distinct number.

We have $\cos3\theta=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta$. Let $x=\cos\theta$, therefore 
$\cos\dfrac{\pi}{12}$, $\cos\dfrac{9\pi}{12}$, $\cos\dfrac{17\pi}{12}$ are roots of $4x^3-3x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$

I want method similar to this to find $P(x)$.

Thank you.

Comment: $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4) $ where the $ r $'s are the roots you specified.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773131/solve-problem-of-trigonometry/773960#773960).

Comment: Exactly the kind of thinking shown in your addendum lead me to look at Chebyshev polynomials. The problem is that to get a quartic you must use a quadruple angle. But neither sines nor cosines of the listed angles multiplied by four have equal sines/cosines. Multiplying by six (and hoping to factor out a quadratic) didn't work either. Thus I went with degree 12 (and factoring out a quartic). The numbers you list are the positive roots of that octic, so it may be possible to do something, if you allow square roots in the coefficients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be not the answer you wanted given that it is of degree 8. But it has integer coefficients, so may be of interest.

If $R_n(x)=T_n(\sqrt{1-x^2})$, where $T_n$ is the [Chebyshev polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of degree $n$, then
$$
T_n(\sin t)=\cos nt
$$
for all $t$. Because $\cos \alpha=0$, iff $\alpha$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, the 12 zeros of 
$$
R_{12}(x)=1 - 72 x^2 + 840 x^4 - 3584 x^6 + 6912 x^8 - 6144 x^{10} + 2048 x^{12}
$$
are the numbers $\sin((2j+1)\pi/24), j=0,1,2,\ldots,23$. Each zero occurs here twice, because $\sin x=\sin (\pi-x)$. We can throw away the zeros that 
correspond to $3\mid 2j+1$, for those are also zeros of 
$$
R_4(x)=1-8x^2+8x^4.
$$
This leaves us with 
$$
P(x)=\frac{R_{12}(x)}{R_4(x)}=1-64x^2+320x^4-512x^6+256x^8.
$$

In addition to the prescribed zeros $P$ vanishes at the negatives of those sines. Observe that $\sin(5\pi/24)=\sin(19\pi/24)$ et cetera.

Comment: I think $R_8(x)=1/2$ works, too?

Answer (score 2):

By a tedious expansion of $P(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\ldots$ that other answers have covered or by using Vieta's formulas, you can find that

$$P(x)=x^4+\left[-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{24}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{24}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{24}\right)\right]x^3$$

$$\ldots+\left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{24}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{24}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{24}\right)\right.$$

$$\left.\ldots+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{24}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{24}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{24}\right)\right]x^2$$

$$\ldots+\left[-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{24}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{24}\right)\right.$$

$$\left.\ldots-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{24}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{24}\right)\right]x$$

$$\ldots+\left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{24}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{24}\right)\right]$$

Using Wolfram Alpha, we can find that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{24}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}$, $\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{24}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}$, $\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{24}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}$ & $\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{24}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}$. You could then substitute these in (I'd be interested to see what it simplifies to). Please note that with an expression so long, I'm bound to have made a mistake somewhere. Thanks for the interesting question.

**Edit**: Using $\sin(\ldots)$ in terms of $e^{(i\ldots)}$, I've managed to express the coefficient of $x^3$ as $\frac{1}{2}(i-1)\left(e^{i\pi/24}+e^{5i\pi/24}\right)-\frac{1}{2}(i+1)\left(e^{-i\pi/24}+e^{-5i\pi/24}\right)$ though can't think where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If $r$ is a root of a polynomial then $(x-r)$ is a factor.  You have four roots.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think the OP wants the coefficients. As far as I know, those $\sin$'s are all rational so $P(x)$ can have integer coefficients. Then again, they may just want it as simple factors :)

Comment: what OP means ?

Comment: @kong if Eul Can is correct, find $\sin{\pi \over 24}$ using a half angle formula and then use $\frac{7\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{6\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{3\pi}{2}$ etc. along with the sum of angles formula for the sine function.

Comment: @EulCan The sines are of course *not* rational, but that does not necesarily prevent from writing the polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Sorry, that was stupid of me. I meant algebraic, not rational. Wolfram Alpha gives a representation of them as roots.

Comment: @idm Sorry for the late response but by "OP", I meant the original poster, who'd asked the question (kong)

Comment: no problem, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may try below :

Say $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$ are roots of polynomial,

$P(x) =  \large x^4-\left(\sum r_1\right)x^3 + \left(\sum r_1r_2\right)x^2 -  \left(\sum r_1r_2r_3\right)x +  r_1r_2r_3r_4 $

Note that the roots define the polynomial only upto a constant factor.

Comment: Your summations need different indices.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\displaystyle\frac{13\pi}{24}-\frac\pi2=\pi\dfrac{(13-12)}{24}=\frac\pi{24}$
 and $\displaystyle\frac{19\pi}{24}-\frac\pi2=\pi\dfrac{(19-12)}{24}=\frac{7\pi}{24}$

So, $\displaystyle\sin\frac{13\pi}{24}=\sin\left(\frac\pi2+\frac\pi{24}\right)=\cos\frac\pi{24}$ and  $\displaystyle\sin\frac{19\pi}{24}=\sin\left(\frac\pi2+\frac{7\pi}{24}\right)=\cos\frac{7\pi}{24}$

So, we need the four degree equation whose roots are $\displaystyle\sin\frac{7\pi}{24},\cos\frac{7\pi}{24};\sin\frac{\pi}{24},\cos\frac{\pi}{24}$

Now the equation whose roots are $\displaystyle\sin\frac{\pi}{24},\cos\frac{\pi}{24}$ is $$t^2-\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{24}+\cos\frac{\pi}{24}\right)t+\sin\frac{\pi}{24}\cos\frac{\pi}{24}=0$$

Now $\displaystyle\sin\frac{\pi}{24}\cos\frac{\pi}{24}=\frac{\sin\dfrac\pi{12}}2$ and $\displaystyle\dfrac\pi{12}=\frac\pi4-\frac\pi6$

Again, $\displaystyle\sin\frac{\pi}{24}+\cos\frac{\pi}{24}=+\sqrt{1+\sin\dfrac\pi{12}}$

The same method should be applied to find the equation whose roots are $\displaystyle\sin\frac{7\pi}{24},\cos\frac{7\pi}{24}$

Comment: @Glen_b, The typo has been rectified. Thanks