# Sum of cosines with a multiplicative factor in the angle and different interval

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, roots-of-unity, trigonometric-series, arithmetic-progressions

I have found the following formula for the sum of cosines in both [here](http://evergreen.loyola.edu/mpknapp/www/papers/knapp-sv.pdf) and [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Holdener200958428.pdf).

\begin{align}
\sum^n_{l=1} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi l}{n}\right) = 0
\end{align}

I would like to know what the sum would be if there is a multiplicative factor $k$ in the angle.

\begin{align}
\sum^n_{l=1} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi l k}{n}\right) = ?
\end{align}

where, $k$ is a positive integer and $1 \le k \le (n-2)/2 $.

Moreover, what if the interval for $l$ is changed from $[1, n]$ to $[0, l-1]$. So,

\begin{align}
\sum^{n-1}_{l=0} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi l k}{n}\right) = ?
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may recall (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933402/proof-of-cos-theta-cos-2-theta-cos-3-theta-cdots-cos-n-theta-frac-sin-f/933438#933438)) that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{l=1}^{n} \cos (l\theta)=\frac{\sin(n\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}\cos ((n+1)\theta/2),\quad \sin(\theta/2)\neq0.
\end{align}
$$ Then by putting $\theta=\dfrac{2 \pi k}{n}$ one gets

> $$
> \sum^n_{l=1} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi l k}{n}\right) =\frac{\color{red}{\sin(\pi k)}}{\sin(\pi l/n)}\cos ((n+1)\pi l/n)=\color{red}{0}
> $$

and

> $$
> \sum^{n-1}_{l=0} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi l k}{n}\right)=\cos (0)+\color{red}{0}-\cos(2\pi k)=0.
> $$

Comment: The first result is a little surprising!  I wouldn't have expected things to cancel out so nicely if all of the intervals didn't add up to $2\pi$.