# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{k=1}^x\sin(k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

According to Wolfram Alpha:
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^x\sin(k) = \frac{\sin(x)-\cot(\frac12)\cos(x)+\cot(\frac12)}2$$
I know I should show some attempt at proving this problem, however I have no idea where to start at all. The only idea I have is setting $S(x) = \sin(1) + \sin(2) + \sin(3) + {...} + \sin(x)$ and then manipulating it somehow to solve for $S(x)$.

Comment: Something similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618462/proving-complex-series-1-cos-theta-cos2-theta-cos-n-theta/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $e^{i\varphi}=\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi$. Then compute
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{x}e^{ik}
$$
and take the imaginary part.