# Are the partial sums of $\sin (n)$ bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

My Calculus II teacher left us the task of finding a sequence that is conditionally convergent, and that if we multiply it by $(-1)^n$ it converges.
I think that sequence could be  $\frac{sen(n)}{n}$. But first I have to prove that it is conditionally convergent, for that I will use the Dirichlet test. And one of his hypotheses is that the partial sums of $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n)$ are bounded , but I don't know how to do it. I would appreciate if  you do not use very complicated things in the proof, since I would also have to demonstrate them.

Comment: Have you looked for [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713995/evaluating-sum-limits-k-1x-sink) questions here? Or [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618462/proving-complex-series-1-cos-theta-cos2-theta-cos-n-theta/) techniques?

Comment: Looks like you have a minor typo... do you mean sequence $\frac{sin (n)}{n}$?