# Can we show a sum of symmetrical cosine values is zero by using roots of unity?

Tags: complex-numbers

Can we show that

$$\cos\frac{\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{3\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{5\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}=0$$

by considering the seventh roots of unity? If so how could we do it?

Also I have observed that

$$\cos\frac{\pi}{5}+\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+\cos\frac{3\pi}{5}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{5}=0$$

as well, so just out of curiosity, is it true that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \cos\frac{k\pi}{n} = 0$$

for all $n$ odd?

Comment: Use complex numbers, something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618462/proving-complex-series-1-cos-theta-cos2-theta-cos-n-theta/2618474#2618474)

Comment: You could use that $\cos (\pi-\theta)=-\cos \theta$ instead, and just pair each cosine with its negative.

Comment: Also, it works for all $n$'s, not just odd ones.

Comment: because the unpaired one is $\cos (\pi /2)$

Comment: You should research how complex numbers can also be represented as vectors

Comment: It works for integers greater than 1. The n=1 case doesn't work.

Comment: @Acccumulation Even for $n=1$, one has $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos(k\pi/n)=0$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that  $$\cos(\pi - \alpha)= - \cos(\alpha)$$ Therefore $$\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{3\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{4\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{5\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{6\pi}{7})=$$

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{3\pi}{7})-\cos(\frac{3\pi}{7})-\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})-\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})=0$$

The same goes for other natural numbers $n$ instead of $7$.

Comment: and even number also

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use Euler's Formula.

The Nth roots of unity = $e^{2\pi k i/N}$ for values of k between $0$ and $N-1$ inclusive.

There sum from k to $N-1$ is a geometric series.

$S= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \ e^{2\pi i k/N}=\frac{1\cdot e^{(2\pi i /N)N}-1}{e^{2\pi i /N}-1}$

The numerator is zero for any N.

But the real part of $S$ is the real part of the individual terms of the sum, i.e. the cosines. The real part of the sum is zero so the sum of the real parts of the roots of unity is 0.

Comment: <pedant>This works only for integer N greater than 1</pedant>

Answer (score 2):

Pointing at the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618462/proving-complex-series-1-cos-theta-cos2-theta-cos-n-theta/2618474#2618474) I left in the comments

> $$1 + \cos\theta + \cos2\theta +... + \cos n\theta = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin[(n+\frac{1}{2})\theta]}{2\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}$$

Then for $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n>0$
$$\cos\frac{\pi}{n+1}+ \cos\frac{2\pi}{n+1} +... + \cos \frac{n\pi}{n+1} =  \frac{\sin\left[(n+\frac{1}{2})\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right]}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}\right)}-\frac{1}{2}=\\
\frac{\sin\left[\frac{2n+1}{2(n+1)}\pi\right]}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}\right)}-\frac{1}{2}=
\frac{\sin\left[\pi-\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}\right]}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}\right)}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=0$$