# $Re(e^{i\theta}+e^{i\theta}+...+e^{ni\theta})=\frac{\cos(n+1)\vartheta\sin n\varphi}{\sin\varphi}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> For any $0<\theta<\pi$ and the integer $n\geqslant 1$ show that:
>
> $$\sin\theta+\frac{\sin 2\theta}{2}+...+\frac{\sin n\theta}{n}>0$$
>
> Denote by $s_n(\theta)$ the left-hand side of the inequality to be shown. Put $\vartheta=\frac{\theta}{2}$ for brevity.
>
> Since $s'_n(\theta)=Re(e^{i\theta}+e^{i\theta}+...+e^{ni\theta})=\frac{\cos(n+1)\vartheta\sin n\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}$

I have been trying to understand how the author gets from here $s'_n(\theta)=Re(e^{i\theta}+e^{i\theta}+...+e^{ni\theta})$to this expression$\frac{\cos(n+1)\vartheta\sin n\varphi}{\sin\varphi}$.

I think $s'_n(\theta)=-n\cos(\theta)$ so I thought of using the sum of geometric series $\frac{a-ar^n}{1-r}$(since $0<\theta<\pi$) to obtain $\frac{\cos(n+1)\vartheta\sin n\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}$. However I got nowhere.

**Question:**

How did the author derive $\frac{\cos(n+1)\vartheta\sin n\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618462/proving-complex-series-1-cos-theta-cos2-theta-cos-n-theta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
e^{i\theta}+e^{i\theta}+...+e^{ni\theta}
&= \dfrac{e^{i\theta}(1-e^{in\theta})}{1-e^{i\theta}} \\
&= \dfrac{e^{i\theta}-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}} \\
&= \dfrac{(e^{i\theta}-e^{i(n+1)\theta})(1-e^{-i\theta})}{|1-e^{i\theta}|^2} \\
&= \dfrac{e^{i\theta}-e^{i(n+1)\theta}-1+e^{in\theta}}{|1-e^{i\theta}|^2} 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
s'_n(\theta)
&= {\bf Re}(e^{i\theta}+e^{i\theta}+...+e^{ni\theta}) \\
&= \dfrac{-1+\cos\theta+\cos n\theta-\cos(n+1)\theta}{2(1-\cos\theta)} \\
&= \dfrac{-2\sin^2\theta/2+2\sin(n+\theta/2)\sin\theta/2}{4\sin^2\theta/2} \\
&= \frac{\cos(n+1)\vartheta\sin n\varphi}{\sin\varphi}
\end{align}
where $\varphi=\theta/2$.

Comment: I have a doubt. You used the geometric series sum formula. However I fail to see how $e^{i\theta}$. Could you clarify it please?

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is messed up: you've got two symbols $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$ for  the same thing. I'll use $\varphi$ for both. To prove
$$
\Re(e^{i\varphi}+e^{i2\varphi}+...+e^{ni\varphi})=\frac{\cos(n+1)\varphi\sin n\varphi}{\sin\varphi},
$$
you can consult the solution to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/933402/215011), remembering that $\varphi$ here is an abbreviation for $\frac\theta2$.