# Show $\sin(\theta) + \sin(2\theta) + ... +\sin(n\theta) = \frac {\sin(n\theta/2)\sin((n+1)\theta/2)} {\sin(\theta/2)}$ using De Moivre's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

[image]

Attempt at part b:

$\sin(\theta)+\sin(2\theta)+...
= \frac {(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})+(e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta})+...+(e^{ni\theta}-e^{-ni\theta})} {2i} \\
= \frac {(1+e^{i\theta}+(e^{i\theta})^2+...+(e^{i\theta})^n) - (1+e^{-i\theta}+(e^{-i\theta})^2+...+(e^{-i\theta})^n)} {2i} \\
= \frac {\frac{(e^{i\theta})^{n+1}-1} {e^{i\theta}-1} - \frac {(e^{-i\theta})^{n+1}-1} {e^{-i\theta}-1}} {2i} \\
= \frac {(e^{i\theta n} - e^{i\theta(n+1)} - e^{-i\theta} + 1) - (e^{-i\theta n} - e^{-i\theta(n+1)} - e^{i\theta} + 1)} {2i(e^{i\theta} - 1)(e^{-i\theta}-1)} \\ 
= \frac {\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta) - (\cos((n+1)\theta)+i\sin((n+1)\theta)) - (\cos(\theta) - i\sin(\theta)) -  (\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta) - (\cos((n+1)\theta)-i\sin((n+1)\theta)) - (\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)))} {2i(1-(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)) - (\cos(\theta) - i\sin(\theta)) + 1)}  \\
= \frac {\sin(n\theta) - \sin((n+1)\theta) + \sin(\theta)} {2(1 - \cos(\theta))} $ \

What to do from here?

Comment: Not a direct answer to yout question, but it could be more clean to work in the complex plane with $z=e^{i\theta}$ and then compute the real and imaginary part of the expression obtained. You can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933402/proof-of-cos-theta-cos-2-theta-cos-3-theta-cdots-cos-n-theta-frac-sin-f?rq=1) as a guide.

Comment: The question itself has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/409). As for completing the proof from where you are, use [sum-to-product formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) in the numerator, and a [half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) in the denominator.

Comment: I got $4\sin^2(\theta/2)$ in the denominator. But which terms do I combine in the numerator? I tried all combinations of 2 and couldn't find a continuation.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin\theta + \sin2\theta + ... + \sin n\theta = \Im(1 + e^{i\theta} + e^{i2\theta} + \ldots + e^{in\theta}) $$
where $\Im (z)$ denotes the imaginary part of $z\in\mathbb C$.

$1 + e^{i\theta} + e^{i2\theta} + \ldots + e^{in\theta}$ is a geometric progresion with common ratio $e^{i\theta}$ and first term unity. I'm sure you can compute that $$1 + e^{i\theta} + e^{i2\theta} + \ldots + e^{in\theta} = \frac{1 - e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}$$
Then,
$$\sin\theta + \sin2\theta + ... + \sin n\theta = \Im\left(\frac{1 - e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}} \right)$$
Now, I'd ask you to use $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$ and half-angle trigonometric identities to simplify the denominator. You should be able to figure out
$$\Im\left(\frac{1 - e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}} \right) =  \frac {\sin(n\theta/2)\sin((n+1)\theta/2)} {\sin(\theta/2)}$$
If you face any trouble, let me know.

Comment: I also tried doing it that way but got to the exact same point

$\frac {\sin(n\theta) - \sin((n+1)\theta) + \sin(\theta)} {2(1 - \cos(\theta))}$

Comment: After this point, you should use $\sin A + \sin B = 2\sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$ on $\sin n\theta + \sin ((-n-1)\theta)$, and the usual half angle identities for $\sin\theta$ and $1- \cos\theta$.