# How do I solve this : $z^4+z^3+z^2+1=0$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, quartics

let z be a complex variable , How do I solve this  : $z^4+z^3+z^2+1=0$  in $\mathbb{C}$ without using numerical method  ?

**Note:** Wolfram alpha show [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E4%2Bz%5E3%2Bz%5E2%2B1%3D0)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x   OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403025/equation-with-high-exponents

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Ferrari's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari.27s_solution). Setting $w=1/z$ gives
$$w^4+w^2+w+1=0.$$
Then, for a new unknown $t$, one has
$$(w^2+t)^2=(2t-1)w^2-w+t^2-1.$$
If the quadratic on the RHS has equal roots we can take a square root.
This is the case iff the discriminant
$$1-4(2t-1)(t^2-1)=0.$$
This is a cubic equation that can be solved by [Cardan's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method).

Answer (score 3):

Write $$z^4+z^3+z^2+1=\left(z^2+\frac{1}{2}z+k\right)^2-\left(\left(2k-\frac{3}{4}\right)z^2+kz+k^2-1\right).$$
Now, choose $k$ such that $k^2-4\left(2k-\frac{3}{4}\right)(k^2-1)=0$ and $2k-\frac{3}{4}>0$.

I got $$k=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{3}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left(-\frac{43}{26\sqrt{13}}\right)\right)=1.0993...$$
and solve two quadratic equations.